# Documenting Macro Functions in C++ with Doxygen

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

How do I document a macro function in C++ using Doxygen, and refer to it in the documentation of my non-Evil code?

More specifically, I have some regular class called "Message" defined in Message.H that users can inherit from to define their own messages. In another file ("MessageHelpers.H") I have a crazy macro like this:

```
//! Users must call this macro to register their messages...
/*! 
   ...lest they be forced to type all sorts of boring and 
   error-prone boiler plate code. 
   blah blah blah... More specific documentation and explanation...
*/
#define REGISTER_MESSAGE_TYPE(MSGTYPE) \
 do_some(MSGTYPE);                     \
 seriously();                          \
 crazy_stuff(MSGTYPE);
```

In the documentation for Message, I would love it if the phrase "REGISTER_MESSAGE_TYPE" could automatically become a link and point to my documentation for the macro. E.g.

```
//! A cool message class
/*! 
   Users can inherit from this class to create their own cool messages.
   Just be sure to call REGISTER_MESSAGE_TYPE after your class definition!
*/
class Message
{
  virtual void doSomeStuff();
};
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html

The [section "Special Commands"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) lists the [`\def` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddef), and the [section "Automatic link generation"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html) describes what you want to link to the macro.

Use `\def` to document a macro separate from the declaration.
Use `#MACRO(params)` to auto-link to said macro definition.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. I tried copying the ABS macro from the example here http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/autolink.html but no documentation was generated, and the reference in my code "#ABS(x)" did not link. I must be doing something wrong in my config file?

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue, but make sure that you document the file somewhere the macro is defined. Try either /*! \file */ or /** @file */, and see if doxygen has generated any warnings. Source is http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/docblocks.html searching for "global objects".   (edit - the slash star characters didn't appear to work, but they should be multi-line comment markers)

Comment: Yup, I have a /*! @file filename.h description... */ at the top of every file.. It's interesting that my macro definition doesn't show up in my MessageHelpers.H documentation at all.

Comment: Using the Doxygen GUI frontend, if I goto the "Expert" tab, the "Preprocessor" topic, and uncheck ENABLE_PREPROCESSING, it stops documenting the sample... But then I get "Warning: explicit link request to 'ABS(x)' could not be resolved" in the output. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Ah ha! The ENABLE_PREPROCESSING did the trick, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen's docs ([Special Commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html)) mentions the [`\def` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddef).

### Example

```cpp
/// \def MIN(x,y)
/// Computes the minimum of \a x and \a y.

/// \def MAX(x,y)
/// Like #MIN(x,y) - but Computes the maximum of \a x and \a y.

/*! 
   \brief Computes the absolute value of its argument \a x.
   \param x input value.
   \returns absolute value of \a x.
*/
#define ABS(x) (((x)>0)?(x):-(x))

#define MIN(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
#define MAX(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(y):(x))
```

**Notes:**

- `\brief` is enough if doc-comment is written  right at top of the macro.
- [Automatic link generation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html) can be used to link to a macro definition, like `#MY_MACRO(params)` or `#MIN(x,y)`
- Also, newer versions support all three comment styles:

  - `///`
  - `/**`
  - `/*!`