# Can doxygen include the documentation of a macro in a class documentation?

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

I have code that looks more or less like this:

```
// foo.h

/**
 * Lalala blablabla
 */
#define Foo_X Foo::doSomething(1)

/**
 * Fofofoo
 */
class Foo {
public:
    static doSomething(int x);
};
```

This will make the documentation of the macro appear in the documentation of the file. However, if possible I would like to have it included in the class documentation of `Foo`. Is this possible?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542626/documenting-macro-functions-in-c-with-doxygen) related question, but if possible I dont want to link the macro documentation, but include the documentation of the macro itself in the class doc.

PS: I know that for this simplified example it doesnt make much sense to use a macro. In the real code I do need the macro and users typically wont ever call `doSomething` directly, but only through the macro.

Comment: why using macros at all?

Comment: @TheTechel read the end of the question

Comment: yeah, I did. Why using a macro for that?

Comment: @TheTechel this is a simplified example for which I would never use a macro. However, for the real code (that is too long and too irrelevant to show here) I do need the macro. Anyhow just assume there is a macro, how can it be documented in the class documentation?